# Text Changing animation same like as ios 8 keyboard text prediction

Tags: ios, autocomplete, ios8, prediction, custom-keyboard

[image]

I am developing app for custom keyboard. I want to add the predication with the animation as apple provide.(Check this GIF image)

In this image you can see the animation happening while word change from **"Include -> Instead -> Instantly -> Install -> Installing"**.

I want to implement the same animation for my keyboard also.

Comment: You could start by getting the differences between the two predictions (notice that only the `clude` part of `include` changes to `stead`). It also looks like the animation is that the letter differences from the first word condense into each other while fading out then fading in and stretching out the letters from the second, all while the entire word's position smooths to the center. I don't know how to animate, though.

Comment: There's some other specific parts of the animation too - notice how the `a` in `instead` shifts instead of fading out since `instantly` already has an `a`

Comment: @crazy Developer how you implemented text prediction can you share sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have to customize a bit, but [TOMSSuggestionBar](https://github.com/TomKnig/TOMSSuggestionBar) is a very good starting point providing you the exact animation and good structure for delegate/datasource.

[image: Demo]